# Check number of messages in input queue

Tags: c#, .net, msmq, nservicebus

Is this possible to get the number of messages inside my InputQueue using NServiceBus and do I need to bypass it and use native MSMQ interface?

---

It's not gonna be a complete monitoring, we've got a system comprising several NSB components and they're monitored through the usage of Windows performance counters. What I'm trying to achieve is just a **simple health check** -> sending a NSB message to a component, its response is to contain let's say DB access status and number of MSMQ messages in its queue. 
That's why I'd like to make it as simple as possible. So the question is: can I check the message number in a simple way or I'd rather need to read the performance counter ?

Comment: Is this for some kind of monitoring you're looking to build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use the System.Messaging.MessageQueue.GetAllMessages() or one of its enumerator methods to get that information. NServiceBus doesn't expose this.